# How can I introduce my VS 2019 to Unreal Engine?

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I have installed VS 2019 and UE4 v.4.11.0 but when I want to open a C++ project in UE4 I see that it can not recognize my VS2019 compiler.
How can I fix it?

[image: New Project dialog]

Comment: I guess maybe try a newer version of UE4 like 4.24 or 4.25 ? Maybe 4.11 is too old to support VS 2019 (just a guess) or install VS 2013 if you specifically need UE 4.11

Answer (score 2):

Support for *Visual Studio 2019* has been added to *Unreal Engine 4.22*: [Release Notes](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Support/Builds/ReleaseNotes/4_22/index.html).

After updating to *Unreal Engine 4.22* or newer, ensure that you have set the **Source Code Editor** to **Visual Studio 2019** in the **Editor Preferences**.
Additionally, if you have created your project with an earlier version of *Visual Studio*, you have to regenerate your project files: right click your `.uproject` file and click **Generate Visual Studio project files**.